# change the color of the png image using expression blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

There might be duplicates of this question but I didnt find any exact solution to my problem.

I have an image. The source of image is a png image named add.png. The shape of add.png is like a plus(+) symbol. Its color is white  at the moment.

I want to change this white color to green when mouse cursor goes over it. So which property of the image should I change to change its color.

I don't want to change the source of image.

**Edit :**

Why I don't want to change the image source :

Basically I have a rectangle and I keep the image over it.
On MouseOver and MouseLeave I change the Fill color of Rectangle using ChangePropertyAction. Now When I click on the image I want to change its source.

But when my program runs I get an error sayin that windows explorer has stopped working.
When I see the output window for errors I get  **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Comment: does this "have" to be a png? why don't you just generate the + with 2 `Line` elements in a Canvas or use a path and then you got all the control you want quite easily and it's vector based.

Comment: Yes, you are right for this image. But I have more images and I am not a great designer. So I cant draw all of them.

Comment: "draw" is not just limited to VS Designer / Blend / xaml direct coding. You can use things like photoshop / illustrator to import graphics too. However if you ain't comfortable with any of them, then yeh that's a problem :(

Comment: Provide a reproducible test case with a minimal code setup, otherwise this will be guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier. to change the image source.
Your options are limited here: Create own effect by derive from  System.Windows.Media.Effects.Effect, call it ColorEffect and implement color change logic there, a similar alternative would be to create separate PixelShader Effect but this is more complex then the Effect above.
Use image processing from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237226/Image-Processing-is-done-using-WPF

Comment: please see the edited question to understand my problem more specifically.